# How to add another provider to the injector?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-di

A framework-agnostic way of phrasing this question is "How to register another service with the service locator?"

The Injector is set up to be immutable, both the interface and the implementation.

```
interface Injector {
    abstract get(token: any, notFoundValue?: any): any;
}
```

interface https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/di/injector.ts
implementation https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/di/reflective_injector.ts

How do you add another provider (dynamically, not via a module)?

How does Angular do this itself when it is loading new modules after bootstrapping, for example via the router?

Answer (score 4):

In order to add a provider to the existing injector you have to extend it by creating a new injector and pass the parent injector:

```
class Comp {
   constructor(existing: Injector) {
      const newInjector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(providers, existing)
   }
}
```

To get more details read [Difference between Reflective Injector and Injector in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45442036/2545680).

> How does Angular do this itself when it is loading new modules after
>   bootstrapping, for example via the router?

It uses a bit different mechanism. When a new module instance is created it's passed the parent injector:

```
class NgModuleRef_ implements NgModuleData, InternalNgModuleRef<any> {    
  constructor(..., public _parent: Injector) {
    initNgModule(this);
  }
```

And then when you request a token it uses this parent injector to resolve dependency if it's not found on the existing injector:

```
NgModuleRef_.get(token, notFoundValue = Injector.THROW_IF_NOT_FOUND) {
     return resolveNgModuleDep(...);
}

export function resolveNgModuleDep(...) {
  ...
  if (found) return instance;
  return data._parent.get(depDef.token, notFoundValue);  <----------------
}
```

Comment: Interesting. It seems this has 2 consquences: (1) You cannot add any injectable to a module after it has been bootstrapped (2) you can not request an injectable of a child module in the parent module. Because its existence is not known to the parent injector.